# Redirecting to a page after clicking button in a popup

Tags: javascript

I have a link in my web page:

```
 <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="ChangePasswordPopup();">Change your password</a>
```

When this link is clicked, the popup opens defined below:

```
function ChangePasswordPopup()
{
    var html=""; // to store the html content

    // Build the content of the change password popup form
    html+="<div class='col-md-12 divChangePasswordPopup' id='divChangePasswordPopup'>";
    html+="<div class='divBackground' id='divBackground' onclick='ClosePopup();'></div>";
    html+="<div class='panel panel-primary divForeground' id='divForeground'>";
    html+="<div class='panel-heading'>";
    html+="Change your password";
    html+="<a href='#' onclick='ClosePopup();' id='CloseButtonLink' title='close'>";
    html+="<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove' style='float: right; font-size: 18px; padding: 3px 3px 0px 0px;'></span>";
    html+="</a>";
    html+="</div>";
    html+="<div class='panel-body'>";
    html+="<form name='frmChangePassword' onsubmit='ChangePassword(this);'>";   .....form textboxes goes here.....
    html+="<button type='submit' name='btnSave' class='btn btn-primary-outline'";
    html+="style='position: relative; float:right;'>Save Changes <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right'></i></button>";
    html+="<br/></div></li></form></div></div></div>";

    $("#divChangePasswordPopup").html(html);    
    disablescroll(); // disable the scrollbar for the webpage    
    return(false); // to prevent the calling form from executing    
}
```

This is working. When I try clicking the save button, I simply want to redirect to another page, so I did this:

```
function ChangePassword(frm)
{
    window.location="login.php";
    return(false); // to prevent the calling form from executing

}
```

But it's not working. If I use that same window.location in a normal button on the web page it's working. But when using it in the popup, it's not working. Anyone knows how I can click a button on the popup form and redirect to the login page?

[the problem in jsfiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/Cavali001/ttw5d73f/4/#&togetherjs=BPAUAwtobK)

Comment: `window.location.href = "login.php";`

Comment: window.location.href isn't working either. although it's working if the button is on the web page

Comment: Change <button type='submit' name='btnSave' to an input of type='submit'

Comment: Try this. In html, pass the event `onsubmit='ChangePassword(this, event);'`. And alter your function to `function ChangePassword(frm, event) {event.preventDefault(); location.assign('login.php');}`

Comment: Works fine. You have any idea why my code worked on a button on the web page but with buttons on the popup?

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
function ChangePassword()
{
    window.location.href = 'login.php';
    return false;
}
```